# How to solve my error sql syntax to create a pivot from a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I created a sql to create a pivot from a subquery. but I'm having trouble with the error. I haven't found a syntax or a way to fix it.
MYSQL version is 8.0.20

the error I got is like this:

> Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
> server version for the right syntax to use near '2022-11-01,max(case when z.dt = '2022-11-02' then tIn end)
> 2022-11-02,max(case w' at line 1 ...

the table from my subquery is like this :

| NIK | name | dt | tIn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | aaaa | 01/11/2022 | 08.00 |
| A | aaaa | 02/11/2022 | 08.00 |
| A | aaaa | 03/11/2022 | OFF |
| A | aaaa | 04/11/2022 | 14.00 |
| A | aaaa | 05/11/2022 | 14.00 |
| .... | .... | .... | .... |
| Z | zzzz | 30/11/2022 | 08.00 |

and the result I expected was like this :

| NIK | name | 01/11/2022 | 02/11/2022 | 03/11/2022 | 04/11/2022 | 05/11/2022 | 06/11/2022 | .... 30/11/2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | aaaa | 08.00 | 08.00 | OFF | 14.00 | 14.00 | 23.00 | OFF |
| B | bbbb | 14.00 | 23.00 | 23.00 | OFF | 08.00 | 08.00 | 14.00 |
| .... | .... | ... | .... | .... | .... | .... | .... | .... |
| Z | aaaa | 14.00 | 08.00 | 14.00 | 23.00 | OFF | 23.00 | 23.00 |

this is my sql query to solve this, but this is have error like the screenshot error:

```
set @m=11; -- for month
set @y=2022; -- for year
set @sql=NULL; -- for sql to pivot


SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when z.dt = ''',
      dt,
      ''' then tIn end) ',
      dt
    )
  ) INTO @sql 
FROM
  (
SELECT
 e.NIK, e.name, u.dt, IFNULL(m.tIn,IF(IFNULL(tm.title,gs.ShiftDesc) LIKE 'OFF%','OFF', CONCAT(gs.tIn,' -(d)'))) tIn
FROM
mstEmp e
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT
      date(CONCAT( @y, '/', @m, '/', t.dt )) dt 
    FROM
        `--utitilityTable1` t 
    WHERE
    t.dt BETWEEN 1 AND DAY (LAST_DAY(CONCAT( @y, '/', @m, '/1' ))))u
LEFT JOIN 
transaksiChangeShift cs ON e.NIK = cs.NIK AND u.dt BETWEEN cs.dateStart AND cs.dateEnd
LEFT JOIN timeTitleMaster tm ON cs.idST = tm.idST
LEFT JOIN timeMaster m ON tm.idST = m.idST AND WEEKDAY(u.dt)=IF(FIND_IN_SET(WEEKDAY(u.dt),m.dayID)=0,NULL,WEEKDAY(u.dt))
LEFT JOIN mstWorkgroup w ON e.idWG = w.idWG
LEFT JOIN mstGroupShift gs ON w.idGroupShift = gs.idGroupShift AND WEEKDAY(u.dt)=gs.Idx)z;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT NIK, name, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM (
SELECT
 e.NIK, e.name, u.dt, IFNULL(m.tIn,IF(IFNULL(tm.title,gs.ShiftDesc) LIKE ''OFF%'',''OFF'', CONCAT(gs.tIn,'' -(d)''))) tIn
FROM
mstEmp e
CROSS JOIN  (
  SELECT
      date(CONCAT( @y, ''/'', @m, ''/'', t.dt )) dt 
    FROM
        `--utitilityTable1` t 
    WHERE
    t.dt BETWEEN 1 AND DAY (LAST_DAY(CONCAT( @y, ''/'', @m, ''/1'' ))))u
LEFT JOIN 
transaksiChangeShift cs ON e.NIK = cs.NIK AND u.dt BETWEEN cs.dateStart AND cs.dateEnd
LEFT JOIN timeTitleMaster tm ON cs.idST = tm.idST
LEFT JOIN timeMaster m ON tm.idST = m.idST AND WEEKDAY(u.dt)=IF(FIND_IN_SET(WEEKDAY(u.dt),m.dayID)=0,NULL,WEEKDAY(u.dt))
LEFT JOIN mstWorkgroup w ON e.idWG = w.idWG
LEFT JOIN mstGroupShift gs ON w.idGroupShift = gs.idGroupShift AND WEEKDAY(u.dt)=gs.Idx)z 
                   GROUP BY NIK
                   ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Quote columns aliases properly. For debugging purposes - comment prep/exec/drop but add `SELECT @sql;` and investigate obtained SQL code correctness.